# Which I should select for Building library ? ES5 or ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, libraries, ecmascript-5

I want to build a simple library in JS (vanilla). I am a bit confused about whether to follow the class-based paradigm or prototypal-based paradigm. ES6 is now in the mainstream, even though ES5 is being used.
What things Should I consider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to write your source code using the latest ES6+ features. Now your javascript library may be consumed by three different types of clients:

1. Browser
2. NodeJS
3. Another library

**1. Browser** - For browser, the best option is to have the source code transpiled into ES5 and then build in IIFE form.

**2. NodeJS** - The best option is to transpile it to es5 and build in CommonJS(CJS)format.

**3. Another library** - The best option is to transpile the source code to es5 but still retain the es5 modules (export/import). You can export the build as esm modules. This helps the bundling tools for better treeshaking while using your library as a dependency.

The mostly used js bundling libraries: Rollup, Webpack and Parcel supports them. You can check them out for more info. 
Happy coding =)

Answer (score 1):

You could use ES6 and transpile the code with babel to ES5 for backward compatibility.

Take a look at this boilerplate for example code.

[npm-module-boilerplate](https://github.com/flexdinesh/npm-module-boilerplate)